# import django settings in app-engine-patch

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, app-engine-patch

I have a problem with Django settings.
My app runs with app-engine-patch.
I added a script that runs without django, and is reached directly via the app.yaml handlers.
I then get this error:

```
File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-0.96/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in _import_settings
raise EnvironmentError, "Environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE
<type 'exceptions.EnvironmentError'>: Environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

I found this tip in google:

```
# Force Django to reload its settings.
from django.conf import settings
settings._target = None

# Must set this env var before importing any part of Django
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
```

But then I got this error:

```
raise EnvironmentError, "Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
<type 'exceptions.EnvironmentError'>: Could not import settings 'settings.py' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named ragendja.settings_pre
```

I think it is a problem with app-engine-patch paths modification, how can I import settings_pre correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to another question, I replaced the beinning with:

```
from common.appenginepatch.aecmd import setup_env 
setup_env(manage_py_env=True)
```

This imports all the settings and my task can run without reference to Django

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings.py'
```

to

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
```

The value of the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is the name of the module (ie, as you would write it in an `import` statement in a Python script), not the path to the module.

Comment: And you've got a file called `settings.py` in the root of your App Engine project?

Comment: Yes.
I think it finds the settings.py file without problem, but this file begins with
    from ragendja.settings_pre import *

Due to app-engine-patch path modification, ragendja is not found (whereas it is imported correctly in the rest of the app).

Comment: So you'll have to do some manual modification of your `sys.path` to make the `ragendja` module available.  Wherever you're doing this `os.environ` modification, make sure the `ragendja` module is in `sys.path`.

Comment: How can I do that? I'm a total newbie to this matter.

Comment: Probably should be a separate question, or a Google search, but here's the short version: `import sys; sys.path.append('path/to/parent/dir/of/ragendja/module/')`.  So, say your `ragendja` module is at `appenginepatch/ragendja/` from the root of your project, you'd use something like `appenginepatch/` as the argument to `sys.path.append`.